# Appending a Textarea not included in Form POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is there a possible case where appending a `textarea` on page load won't be included inside the `form` post? however, hardcoding it in PHP works fine?

I would post the whole code, but I'm using PyroCMS fieldTypes and I'm not sure if many know it.

Here's the JS code:

```
$(function() {
      $(".list_field").append('<li><textarea name="work_and_education[3]" class="item_input" placeholder="List item content..."></textarea><div class="btn gray add" id="add_btn">+</div><div class="btn gray remove" id="remove_btn">-</div></li>');
});
```

UPDATE:

Here's how the html looks like after loading the page:
The textarea that contains values are done by php.

```
                        <div class="input">
                            <ul class="list_field" id="work_and_education">
                            <li><textarea name="work_and_education[0]" class="item_input" placeholder="List item content...">testin1</textarea><div class="btn gray add" id="add_btn">+</div><div class="btn gray remove" id="remove_btn">-</div></li>
                            <li><textarea name="work_and_education[3]" class="item_input" placeholder="List item content..."></textarea><div class="btn gray add" id="add_btn">+</div><div class="btn gray remove" id="remove_btn">-</div></li>
                            <li><textarea name="work_and_education[2]" class="item_input" placeholder="List item content...">testing2</textarea><div class="btn gray add" id="add_btn">+</div><div class="btn gray remove" id="remove_btn">-</div></li>
                            </ul>                         
                        </div>
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the textarea actually _is_ part of the form, and doesn’t by some mistake end up outside of it in the DOM …?

Comment: I've updated the question. It's a bug in a plugin I downloaded from Github. I really don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, however if you are using it to add many textareas, they should have unique names and possibly id's.

Comment: I've updated the question. It's a bug in a plugin I downloaded from Github. I really don't know what's the problem.

Comment: There was a problem with the framework core code, I had to modify it and push it in Github. Funny how all this started :)